# sublime text 3: How to open command console with correct python version

Tags: python, cmd, console, sublimetext3

I have multiple python version installed in Ubuntu OS. I've set up sublime text 3 (ST3) to run python2 code successfully. But I would like to have the option to run python code using command console during debugging as well. But I found that when I open the cmd console, the python version that it used is not the same of the python that I'm building my python code. To be exact, cmd console called python3, while I would like it to use python2. Any way to set which default python that the cmd console call? Thanks.

Comment: The console in Sublime uses a built in version of python 3.3; it does not require, call, or interact in any way whatsoever with any python that may or may not be installed anywhere on your computer, which includes other versions of python or any python libraries you have installed. It cannot be changed by anyone except the developer of sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Build System > New Build System

You can set it up there and choose your python binary